# parsing json in azure sql with OPENJSON

Tags: json, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to parse a json file into sql using `OPENJSON`. I have a structure which looks like this:

```
{
    "definitions": {            
        "Event": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "System-generated Id"
                },
                "transactionDateTime": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "RFC3339-compliant, system-generated timestamp"
                },
                "Name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "blah"
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to read the `type` field for each item in the `properties` section with a select query.

```
drop table if exists #temp;
SELECT * into #temp FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\swagger.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(BulkColumn, '$.definitions.Event.properties');
select * from #temp
```

This returns a table `#temp` with a column called `[key]` which contains `id`,`DateTime`,`Name`. In the adjacent column called `value` there is bulk json data e.g. `{ "type":"string", "description": "....."}`

For each item in `[key]` column, i'd like to have an adjacent column with the `type`, e.g. `string`. I'd like to do this without hard-coding the `[key]` field-names into the sql query.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the following solution, using a variable to import the json first, then calling `OPENROWSET` to read the json.

```
DECLARE @json varchar(max);
SELECT @json = BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\swagger.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j;

DROP TABLE if exists #temp;
SELECT value INTO #temp FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.definitions.Event.properties')
```